# Why is my matplotlib bar chart compressing the x-axis when I do 'log'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, logarithm

I am trying to make a bar chart with matplotlib for python. I can make a normal chart, but when I put it in logarithmic mode so that I can see the data better, the x-axis looks as if it is compressing. What is going on?
Note: all data records have a minimum value of 1.

```
    x = [t[0] for t in data]
    y = [t[1]  for t in data]

    x_pos = np.arange(len(x))

    plt.bar(x_pos, y, color='blue', log=False)
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlim([0, len(x)])
    #plt.yscale('log')
    #plt.semilogy(x_pos, np.exp(-x_pos/5.0))
    plt.savefig(output_path + '/' + filename)
```

Yields: [image]

But just by changing `log=False` to `log=True` I get:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I just want to get a compressed view of the first graph on the y axis. As you can see, I also tried `yscale('log')` but I get the same result.

Thanks!

EDIT: Looks like it has something to do with the previous lines, when I remove the first line it works fine, but is unsorted:

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)

    # tuples (pair,count)
    x = [t[0] for t in data]
    y = [t[1]  for t in data]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't compressing your x-axis; the minimum value of your second plot's y-axis is 1 (10^0), which it appears is the height of the smallest set of bars. Hence, the rightmost bars are off the **y** scale on your semilog plot.

Try adding, *e.g.*,

```
plt.ylim([0.1, 100])
```

to enforce the visibility of the rightmost bars. (A log-scale axis can't have a minimum limit of 0, for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Thank you, sir! That was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a log scale on the y axis and not the x use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.semilogy(x,y) #plots log on y axis

plt.semilogx(x,y) #plots log on x axis
```

Alternatively, you can just set the axis' to log:

```
ax = plt.subplot(224)

ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")

plt.bar(x,y)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It still compresses on the x axis, just like in my example.

Comment: I tried both methods but I get the same result. The X axis is compressed, like in my second picture.